# A lyrical genius

Tags: music

[Chorus]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
**The answer is _______!!!**

[Outro]
[image]

Hint:

> These are the lyrics to a commercial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> **Clear** (which you'll find in the lyrics below)

This is a rebus of the

> [2018 Lebron James 'Sprite Cranberry' Commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtNKG9LUz-w).

Here is the chorus and the outro

> [Sprite cranberry lyrics](https://genius.com/Sprite-sprite-cranberry-lyrics). 
>  By looking at the rebus we can see an image of fire works mostly associated with new year (around **christmas times**), a **glass of sprite**, a symbol for **Query** language and some **cranberries.** (I don't really know what the symbol for **scratch** programming (the image of the cat) is suppose to mean. Perhaps it just goes together with the **Query** to hint *language*.) 
>  **Edit:** As @Lezzup points out in the comments, the image of the cat is  called a **sprite.**

This song

> is clearly based on the more famous song [It's the Most Wonderful Time of the Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_the_Most_Wonderful_Time_of_the_Year) using some wordplay to fit the commercial.

Comment: The image of the cat is also called a [sprite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_(computer_graphics))

Comment: @Lezzup Ah, I'll make an edit a bit later